# How to get etag in google Admin SDK results?

Tags: google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk

Does anyone knows how I can easily retrieve etag headers if I use google admin SDK  in Java.
I mostly using directory API. But for some reason object returned do not give Etag information. This can be very handy to avoid retrieving some information in case data is not changed on the server. ( For example if user was not modified) 
THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the [latest version](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/admin/directory_v1) of the library you can do:

```
Users users = list.execute();
String etag = users.getETag();
```